# Get variable value created inside a function

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I want to get a variable from a function to use this variable in another function.
Simple example:

```py
from tkinter import *

def test():

    intro = "I am "
    name = "Phil"
    text = intro + name


def printresult():
    print(text)


root = Tk()
root.title("Test")

testbutton = Button(root, text="Test", command = test)
printbutton = Button(root, text="print Test", command = printresult)

testbutton.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
printbutton.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

mainloop()
```

If I press the `testbutton` and afterwards the `printbutton`, then I get the error "name 'text' is not defined".

So how am I able to get the `text` variable from the `def test()` to use it in the `def printresult()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save the value somewhere well known:

```py
from tkinter import *

def test():
    intro = "I am "
    name = "Phil"
    text = intro + name
    test.text = text     # save the variable on the function itself


def printresult():
    print(test.text)


root = Tk()
root.title("Test")

testbutton = Button(root, text="Test", command = test)
printbutton = Button(root, text="print Test", command = printresult)

testbutton.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
printbutton.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using tkinter, I'd use a `StringVar` to store the result. Using a string var makes it easy for other tkinter widgets to use the value.

```
from tkinter import *

def test():

    intro = "I am "
    name = "Phil"
    text.set(intro + name)


def printresult():
    print(text.get())


root = Tk()
root.title("Test")

text = StringVar()

testbutton = Button(root, text="Test", command = test)
printbutton = Button(root, text="print Test", command = printresult)

testbutton.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
printbutton.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

mainloop()
```